# glGetString(GL_VERSION) returns 1.1.0, even though card supports 2.1

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glew

I'm having a small problem with SDL2 and OpenGL.
I've been trying to get VBOs working (specifically ARB objects) and have thus far been unsuccessful. Through various searches around, I've found how ancient the onboard GL.h is, and opted for glew.h instead - thus allowing me to use functions past 1.1.

Whilst attempting to use glGenBuffersARB, I found that even after calling glewInit, the functions pointer was empty.

However, visualinfo reports that OpenGL is 2.1.0, and that GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object is able to be accessed - the SDL context seems to default to Microsoft's 1.1.0, and doesn't allow me to rectify the null pointer.

I'm (sadly) using an Intel HD Graphics chipset, on an Acer Aspire 5733.

How can I get SDL to recognize the 2.1.0 on the chipset? (Or am I completely wrong in my approach to this?)

### **EDIT**

Here's the code that was requested:

astralmain.cpp (inits SDL + OpenGL context)

```
bool AstralGame::onInit()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) return false;
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 2);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, 2);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 5);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 5);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 5);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 32);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1);

    if ((currWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(ASTRAL_TITLE" "ASTRAL_VERSION, 100, 100, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL)) == nullptr)
    {
        a_ErrorManager::panic("Window couldn't be created\n");
        return false;
    }
    if ((currContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(currWindow)) == NULL)
    {
        a_ErrorManager::panic("OpenGl context couldn't be created\n");
    }
    printf((char*)glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    glewExperimental = TRUE;
    glewInit();
    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);
    textureManager->startUp();
    errorManager->startUp();
    renderManager->startUp();
    if (glGenBuffersARB == nullptr) printf("This entire program will not work!");
    cube = new a_GL_Cube(textureManager->getTexture("astral")->texture);
    //Start initting GL functions
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    cube->buildVert(1.0f);
    return true;

}
```

a_GL3DPrimitives.cpp (builds vertices for cubes, error occurs)

```
void a_GL_Cube::buildVert(float size)
{
    float pVt[72] = { -size, -size, size, -size, size, size, size, size, size, size, -size, size,
        size, -size, size, size, -size, -size, size, size, -size, size, size, size,
        size, size, size, -size, size, size, -size, size, -size, size, size, -size,
        size, size, -size, size, -size, -size, -size, -size, -size, -size, size, -size,
        -size, size, size, -size, size, -size, -size, -size, -size, -size, -size, size,
        -size, -size, size, -size, -size, -size, size, -size, -size, size, -size, size };
    float pTt[48] = { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 };

    vboVName = 0;
    vboTName = 0;

    unsigned int* test = &vboVName;
    glGenBuffersARB(1, &vboVName); <======= Null Pointer
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vboVName);
    glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(float)* 72, pVt, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);

    glGenBuffersARB(1, &vboTName);
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vboTName);
    glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(float)* 48, pTt, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);

    delete[] pVt;
    delete[] pTt;
}
```

Comment: Please include the code you use to request a pixel format with SDL. Also note that in Windows Vista+ the platform ships with D3D10 capable drivers (provided hardware support) but completely lacks an OpenGL ICD (Installable Client Driver). You often need to acquire drivers from the first-party IHV in order to correct this situation and not the gimped WHQL drivers that come with Windows.

Comment: I looked into getting first-party drivers for my machine - Sadly, Intel's _wonderful_ service doesn't have Win8 drivers for the first gen Intel HD Graphics set, so nothing there.

Comment: Things to try: **1.** Remove all your `SDL_GL_SetAttribute()` calls.  You may be over-constraining the pixel format.  **2.** Remove [only the `SDL_GL_CONTEXT_*` calls](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GLattr#OpenGL) since you aren't trying to request a GL 3.x context.

Comment: Disabled the calls, set SDL_GL_DEPTH to 16, everything is working now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to try:

1. Remove all your `SDL_GL_SetAttribute()` calls. You may be over-constraining the pixel format.  Add them back in one at a time to figure out where you overstepped.
2. Remove [only the `SDL_GL_CONTEXT_*` calls](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GLattr#OpenGL) since you aren't trying to request a GL 3.x context.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've misunderstood the purpose of `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`

First of all you of course need to create an OpenGL Context before you can even call `glGetString()`. When you're creating an OpenGL Context, you specify the version of OpenGL you want to use.

Then when you call `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` it will return the OpenGL version of the current OpenGL Context in use.

### Extra

As I can see you tagged your question [glew](/questions/tagged/glew) you can use GLEW to see which OpenGL versions your computer supports.

```
std::cout << "OpenGL 2.0: " << ((GLEW_VERSION_2_0 != 0) ? "Available" : "Unavailable") << std::endl;
std::cout << "OpenGL 2.1: " << ((GLEW_VERSION_2_1 != 0) ? "Available" : "Unavailable") << std::endl;

std::cout << "OpenGL 3.0: " << ((GLEW_VERSION_3_0 != 0) ? "Available" : "Unavailable") << std::endl;
std::cout << "OpenGL 3.1: " << ((GLEW_VERSION_3_1 != 0) ? "Available" : "Unavailable") << std::endl;
std::cout << "OpenGL 3.2: " << ((GLEW_VERSION_3_2 != 0) ? "Available" : "Unavailable") << std::endl;
std::cout << "OpenGL 3.3: " << ((GLEW_VERSION_3_3 != 0) ? "Available" : "Unavailable") << std::endl;

std::cout << "OpenGL 4.0: " << ((GLEW_VERSION_4_0 != 0) ? "Available" : "Unavailable") << std::endl;
std::cout << "OpenGL 4.1: " << ((GLEW_VERSION_4_1 != 0) ? "Available" : "Unavailable") << std::endl;
std::cout << "OpenGL 4.2: " << ((GLEW_VERSION_4_3 != 0) ? "Available" : "Unavailable") << std::endl;
std::cout << "OpenGL 4.3: " << ((GLEW_VERSION_4_3 != 0) ? "Available" : "Unavailable") << std::endl;
std::cout << "OpenGL 4.4: " << ((GLEW_VERSION_4_4 != 0) ? "Available" : "Unavailable") << std::endl;
```

Be aware that you of course need to have created an OpenGL Context and called `glewInit()` before you can do the above.

*I'm not sure about the following, but also if you do something like the above and it outputs "Unavailable", when you for sure know it's Available, then it might have something to do with the OpenGL version the current OpenGL Context is using.*

Comment: I'm calling glGetString(GL_VERSION) after the context has been instated - As I'm using SDL2, I'm forced to use SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION and SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION - both of which (for some reason) don't add up to squat when initializing the OpenGL context with SDL. EDIT: As per the extra, all return unavailable. This is, again, after context creation and glewInit(), and in spite of visualinfo reporting as 2.1.

Comment: Did you try using something like GLFW and see if you're able to create a context using OpenGL 2.1 ?